# Why is it necessary to find extreme values of L-functions?

Tags: analytic-number-theory, l-functions, extreme-value-analysis

Apparently I have been exploring Riemann Zeta Function and have lately come across $L$-functions. After going through few papers, I realised that many mathematicians are giving their full time knowing the extreme values of $L$-functions. I need to know the following:

1. What is the motivation to study these areas?
2. What information do we get after finding central values of these functions?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you asking about extreme values or central values?

Comment: See OP's previous question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3865703/276986

Answer (score 1):

The OP probably meant the local extrema of the $\Bbb{R\to R}$ function $$\Xi(t)=(1/2+it)(1/2-it)\pi^{-(1/2+it)/2}\Gamma((1/2+it)/2)\zeta(1/2+it)$$ obtained from the functional equation.

Under the RH $$\Xi(t)=\Xi(0)\lim_{K\to \infty}\prod_{k=1}^K (1-\frac{t}{\Im(\rho_k)})^{e_k}(1+\frac{t}{\Im(\rho_k)})^{e_k}$$ where $\rho_k$ are the non-trivial zeros of $\zeta$ and $e_k$ their multiplicity.

$f_K(t)=\prod_{k=1}^K (1-\frac{t}{\Im(\rho_k)})^{e_k}(1+\frac{t}{\Im(\rho_k)})^{e_k}$ is a real polynomial whose all roots are real, its derivative $f_K'$ has at least one zero between each consecutive zero of $f_K$ (at the maximum of $|f_K|$ between those consecutive zeros) so we obtain $2K-1+\sum_{k=1}^K 2(e_k-1)$ zeros for $f_K'$,  thus we have found them all.

Since the zeros of $f_K'$ converge locally uniformly to those of $\Xi'$ we know all the zeros of $\Xi'$,

and hence if the RH is true then there is exactly one local extremum of $\Xi$ between two consecutive zeros.

It works the same way for other L-functions.

Comment: The OP probably didn't mean this; the OP probably meant something like the study of $\max_{t \in [T,T+1]} |\zeta(1/2 + it)|$, or analogous problems for other families of $L$-functions.

Comment: Yes @PeterHumphries, I did mean that. Not just maximum, even minimum. Where does it consequently lead to? Is it so very necessary to understand them?